# Searching only bmp file - Google

Tags: google-search

I'd like to search only bmp file in google; to do this i used for example the string:

filetype:bmp keyboard arrow

but it doesn't find anything. How can i search only bmp file on google?

Comment: Enclose the whole string with second brackets [ ]

Comment: Hello @WasifHasan ther result is the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Search for "keyboard arrow" at https://images.google.com
2. Open the Settings menu and choose "Advanced search"

   [image]
3. Scroll down, select the file type and hit Advanced Search:

   [image]
4. Profit!

   [image]

The direct link to that page is https://www.google.com/search?as_st=y&tbm=isch&hl=en&as_q=keyboard+arrow&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&cr=&as_sitesearch=&safe=images&tbs=ift:bmp – note the `ift:bmp` at the end but using that as a search term doesn't help. So it seems you have to go for this multi-step approach.

Comment: Hello @Glorfindel thank you very much for your very useful answer.